# How to calculate individual covariances and residual covariances in a multivariate mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, covariance-matrix, glmmtmb

I need enlightenment in calculating individual covariances and residual covariances in a multivariate mixed model. I'm going to use the dataset 'Owls', present in the **glmmTMB** package to replicate where I'm trying to get at.

Suppose my response variables are *ArrivalTime* and *NegPerChick*; *Nest* is the random term; *FoodTreatment* and *SexParent* are the fixed terms. I used the following [vignette](https://mac-theobio.github.io/QMEE/MultivariateMixed.html) to help me build a multivariate mixed model using the 'glmmTMB' function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glmmTMB)

owls.melt <- Owls %>%
  modify_if(is.numeric, scale) %>% # scale all numeric variables
  select(-c(SiblingNegotiation, BroodSize, logBroodSize)) %>%
  # convert response variables to long format
  gather(key = "measure", value = "value", c(ArrivalTime, NegPerChick)) %>%
  drop_na()

mvm <- glmmTMB(value ~ measure * FoodTreatment * SexParent - 1 +
                 (measure - 1 | Nest), data = owls.melt)
```

Short version, I would like to publish a table similar to this one: [image]

Long version, I would like to obtain the among-nest covariance and the residual (within-nest) covariance between the two response variables, *ArrivalTime* and *NegPerChick*. In the [paper where I withdrew the above table](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physbeh.2018.11.023), the authors use the ASReml-R package to calculate those parameters. Sadly, that package is commercial, and so not an option for me to use. They also calculated the confidence intervals using a package that depends on the ASReml-R package, thus another dead end. I would be greatly appreciated to someone who knows how to extract those parameters and their respective confidence intervals using non-commercial packages!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are fitting a simple linear mixed effects model with a random slopes for `measure` for each level of the `Nest` grouping factor. As such, the same model could be fitted with the **nlme** package that calculates confidence intervals for the variance components using the `intervals()` function - for more info check [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/intervals.lme.html).

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, Dimitris! I've tried your suggestion. It does give the confidence intervals, but for the among-nest variance and residual variance of each response variable, which is not what I'm interested in. Instead, what I want are the _covariances_ between the response variables. Unless you're talking about the 'cor' component of the random effects. But I thought that was the within-nest correlation?

Comment: Is `measure` coded as a factor? If yes, then you should get the covariances between the random effects of the different outcomes, and their 95% confidence intervals using `intervals`.

Comment: I found a package that can get me the information I was looking for, but not the confidence intervals: the **sommer** package. Your solution did not work out for me, Dimitris.